# editText lineSpacingExtra issue

Tags: android, android-edittext, css

I have an editText with layout:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
        />
```

but the text is not centered vertically because of `lineSpacingExtra`. Here is how it looks:

[image]

how to make it so I keep `lineSpacingExtra` tag but have text centered vertically?

Comment: lineSpacingExtra seems to be used for spacing lines of text of same editText. You should use margin for spacing multiple editTexts. Using spacing and center_vertical in the same editText? I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: @cosmincalistru I will have more then two lines in my editText and client asked to be a custom distance between the lines, so this is the only way that I've found to set this distance

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to simulate this but not an actual solution. You can add padding top but it's not a safe solution.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="18dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
    android:text="test" />
```

Comment: this is not a solution because the only "padding" must be lineSpacingExtra/2, how theory says (this extra space theoretically is distributed above and below editText).

Comment: i told you it's a hack not a solution. and your theory is bad. they say the space is distributed between lines. that does not include the top of first line.

Comment: indeed, android:lineSpacingExtra : Extra spacing between lines of text.

but:

public void setLineSpacing (float add, float mult)  : Sets line spacing for this TextView. Each line will have its height multiplied by mult and have add added to it.

So here doesn't say that added value is just above or below. In practice, I saw adding just below... which is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

To me this feels like a familiar issue I first experienced when designing forms on the web and using the incorrect CSS attributes in an attempt to give text fields more space.

So -- why not forget about this `lineSpacingExtra` attribute and just use padding top & padding bottom?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just done it TextView it works fine.

```
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtWelcome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/activation"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
            android:textAppearance="@style/CleverFingerThemeLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/DFTextColor" />
```

If I put android:lineSpacingExtra="20dp"

I get more gap between lines.

In my example @string/activation = is a multiple line text.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the following:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
android:lineSpacingExtra="1" 
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0dp"
```

your extra padding should go away!

Comment: `lineSpacingMuliplier` must be a floating point value without unit, such as "1.4"

Answer (score -4):

```
android:lineSpacingExtra="Your Value" 
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="Your Value"
```